# Added a Column to a Table Which is a Target For Multiple Maps. How can I get the new column into informatica without re-importing?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, etl, informatica

I am adding a column to a table in my database. This table is a target which is used by multiple mappings. The targets don't automatically update when you add columns in your database, so how can I get my target to pull in this new column without having to re-import it as a target?

Comment: Why don’t  you just edit the target definition in Informatica?

Comment: @NickW, OP may not be using shared targets :). So, he/she is trying to avoid modifying lots of maps ( my guess).

Comment: @KoushikRoy, I'm still a bit new to informatica so I'm not sure if shared targets just means that any authorized user can use the same targets as me), but if so, then I am. So NickW's solution would work then I suppose, right?

Comment: @NickW, I saw that as a solution, but I was unsure if the target would register that a new column was added in the database if all I did was edit the target definition.

Comment: Yes, nicks solution will always work.